# How to split x-axis as decile in R and make ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile

Hi I am wondering how to split x-axis as decile in R and make ggplot?

I currently have age range data and NO2 pollution data. The two datasets share the same geographic reference named ward. I wish to plot my demographic data in quantiles of equal number of ward (Total 298).

[image: My Table]

I tried the quantile regression in R where I used the following:

```
library(SparseM) 
library(quantreg)
mydata<- read.csv("M:/Desktop10/Test2.csv") 
attach(mydata) 
Y <- cbind(NO2.value)
X <- cbind(age.0.to.4, age..5.to.9, age.10.to.14, age.15.to.19, age.20.to.24, age.25.to.29, age.30.to.44, age.45.to.59, age.60.to.64, age.65.to.74, age.75.to.84, age.85.to.89, age.above.90) 
quantreg.all <- rq(Y ~ X, tau = seq(0.05, 0.95, by = 0.05), data=mydata) 
quantreg.plot <- summary(quantreg.all) 
plot(quantreg.plot)
```

But what I get are not what I expected as the y-axies is not the NO2 data.

The ideal plot is attached:

[image: ideal plot]

Many thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Please, do not post images of your dataset but share the output of `dput(mydata)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think the `cut` function combined with the `quantile` function will create the deciles. Here's an example with fake data.

In the code below, we use the `cut` function to split the data into deciles and we use the `quantile` function to set the `breaks` argument for `cut`. This tells `cut` to group the data into 10 groups of equal size, from smallest values of `NO2` to largest.

`group_by(age)` means we create the deciles separately for each `age` group. This means that there are equal numbers of subjects within each decile in a given age group, but the NO2 cutoff values for each decile are different for different age groups. To create deciles over the data as a whole, just remove `group_by(age)`. This will result in the same NO2 cutoff values for each decile across all age groups, but within a given age group, the number of subjects will not be the same in each decile.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(NO2=c(runif(600, 0, 10), runif(400, 1, 11)), 
                 age=rep(c("0-10","11-20"), c(600,400)))

# Create decile groups
dat = dat %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  mutate(decile = cut(NO2, breaks=quantile(NO2, probs=seq(0,1,0.1)), 
                      labels=10:1, include.lowest=TRUE),
         decile = fct_rev(decile))
```

Now we plot using `ggplot2`. The `stat_summary` function returns the mean for each `decile` in each `age` group.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(decile, NO2, colour=age, group=age)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point") +
  expand_limits(y=0) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your answer and explicit documentation. It shows: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "fct_rev". The fac_rev function is the reverse order of levels right? I have installed the forcats package. Many thanks again

Comment: Yes, `forcats::fct_rev`. Base R equivalent would be `decile=factor(decile, levels=rev(levels, decile))`.

Comment: dplyr now has `ntile()` which can create deciles like this